# Remove strings from HashMap not listed in a List

Tags: java

I have a hashMap with the following declaration:

```
Map<String, Integer> terms = new HashMap<>();
```

and a List as follow:

```
List<String> allTerms = new ArrayList<>();
```

The hashMap and the List contain Strings.

I want to remove all Strings stored in the hashMap not listed in the declared List.
What is the better way to do that?

Comment: Without providing the type information for the map it's impossible to say what you are asking for. Preferably also provide the information about business nature of entries in map and the contents of list.

Comment: `allTerms.forEach(terms::remove)`.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. I just edit the question.

Comment: School assignment right? You should try it yourself to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    static boolean match = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7");
        map.put("Test1", 1);
        map.put("Test66", 2);
        map.put("Test3", 3);
        map.put("Test4", 4);
        map.put("Test123", 5);


        map.forEach((k, v) -> {
            match = false;
            list.forEach(s -> {
                if (k.equals(s))
                    match = true;
            });
            if(match)
                map1.put(k,v);
        });
        map = map1;
        map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Test1
Test4
Test3
```

Comment: This is an `O(n*m)` solution, copying the `List` to a `Set` would be a much smarter choice.

Comment: @BoristheSpider i was thinking about that solution, but `Set` will only remove duplicates, right?

Comment: `contains` is `O(1)` for a `Set`. You are essentially rewriting `List.contains`, which is `O(n)`. Further, this code is an abuse of streams and lambdas; but lets ignore that for now.

Comment: @Kittani i know its working, but take a look at Boris's solution.